# const object assigning its address to pointer to non-const in its constructor

Tags: c++, constants, undefined-behavior

Why does the following code compile and the compiler doesn't issue any error or even a warning? AFAIK, the code has undefined behavior. But what is the reason the compiler is silent about this?

```
class C1;

class C0 {
public:
    C1* c1{ nullptr };
};

class C1 {
public:
    int i{ 0 };
    C0 c0; 
    C1() { c0.c1 = this; }
};

int main()
{
    const C1 c1; 
    return c1.c0.c1->i = 123;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think the code has undefined behavior?

Comment: @songyuanyao, modifying `const` object through non-const path

Comment: what I dont get is why `c0.c1 = this;` in the ctor is fine. `C0::c1` is pointer to non-const `C1` but we are constructing a `const C1`

Comment: There are several constructs leading to UB, hard to detect them. (especially when code might be split along several TUs.)

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818: Would you consider also `this->i = 42;` invalid in `C1`'s constructor?

Comment: @Jarod42 actually I did. I must be a bit confused atm, hope some coffee can help

Comment: I don't get what exactly is not clear about the problem for someone who's voted to close the question.

Comment: The compiler doesn't have to tell you about undefined behaviour (if the compiler *has* to tell you about it, it is *not* undefined).

Comment: when you say "this should not compile" you should explain why. Same for undefined behavior. And one problem, prabably just with wording, is "But what is the reason the compiler is silent about this?", because the compiler needs not diagnose UB, by the very definition of UB

Comment: This question got me curious. I wonder how much code that would break if, during construction, `*this` as lvalue was always non-`const` (as it is now), but if used as an `rvalue` it would be _cv-qualified_ as in its declaration? `c0.c1 = ...;` would then be ok in the ctor if used to point to a non-`const` `C1`, but `this` would be a pointer to a `const` `C1`, so `c0.c1 = this;` would fail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Intro: [`class.ctor`](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.ctor#general-5)

"*A constructor can be invoked for a `const`, `volatile` or `const volatile` object. `const` and `volatile` semantics (`[dcl.type.cv]`) are not applied on an object under construction. They come into effect when the constructor for the most derived object (`[intro.object]`) ends.*"

```
class C1;

class C0 {
public:
    C1* c1 = nullptr; // c1 is pointing to a non-const C1
};

class C1 {
public:
    int i = 0;
    C0 c0;
    C1() {
        // *this is non-const in the constructor.
        // hence, c1, that is a pointer to a non-const C1 can be assigned
        // to point at this:
        c0.c1 = this;
    };

    void foo() { // However, ...
        // calling this function when *this is const would fail.
        c0.c1 = this;
    }
};

int main() {
    const C1 c1;
    //c1.foo(); // nope

    // now this:
    c1.c0.c1->i = 123;

    // becomes a sneaky way of doing this:
    const_cast<C1&>(c1).i = 123;          // undefined behavior
}
```

The compiler can't be held responsible. It can't keep track of all the possible ways the language permits you to circumvent type safety, so instead the language standard simply states ([`dcl.type.cv`/4](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.cv#4)):

"*Any attempt to modify (`[expr.ass]`, `[expr.post.incr]`, `[expr.pre.incr]`) a `const` object (`[basic.type.qualifier]`) during its lifetime (`[basic.life]`) results in undefined behavior.*".

Comment: Is there some line in the standard that states an object is always non-const under construction? And what is the rationale behind this?

Comment: @Oleksa I added that paragraph to the intro of the answer. The rationale is most probably that the object wouldn't be able to hold much of a state without being able to assign values to its members.

Comment: @Oleksa: It would make all code which use body to "initialize" the object invalid.

Answer (score 3):

Standard doesn't mandate to diagnose this problem.

It is hard or impossible to identity the problem in general case. (even more when code is split in different translation Units (TUs)).

Compilers try to diagnose some Undefined Behavior (UBs), even if they don't have to, to help developers.

`constexpr` are more constrained and disallow UBs (but also disallows valid constructs).

[Here](https://godbolt.org/z/57j6E74q1)

```
class C1;

class C0 {
public:
    C1* c1{ nullptr };
};

class C1 {
public:
    int i{ 0 };
    C0 c0; 
    constexpr C1() {
        c0.c1 = this;
    }
};

[[maybe_unused]] constexpr C1 c_ok{}; 

constexpr C1 foo()
{
    const C1 c_ko{}; 
    
    c_ko.c0.c1->i = 123;
    return c_ko;
}

[[maybe_unused]] constexpr C1 c_ko = foo();
```

Compilers (except msvc :-/) detects the UB with error similar to

> note: modification of object of const-qualified type 'const int' is not allowed in a constant expression.